# Overloading operator->

Tags: c++

The code is about overloading `->` operator to let iterator's current point points to the dataobject (data below).

```
dataType* operator -> () const {
    if (current == NULL) {
        throw std::invalid_argument(
            "Attempting to dereference NULL in dlistIterator");
    }
    return &(current->data);
}


int main()
{
    dlist<myData> myList;
    dlistIterator<myData> itr;
    for (itr = myList.begin(); itr != myList.end(); itr++)
    {
        itr->printData();
    }
}
```

If I create a `myData` object lets say `abc`, `itr->printData();`, is like 
`&abcprintData()`? It really confuses me a lot.

Comment: I'm not sure but, as I remember, in `C++` you can't overload the operators like `.`, `->`, `unary &`, `unary *`.

Comment: @FalconUA: You can overload them, with the exception of `.`.

Comment: You're not using `dataType::operator->` at all here.

Comment: @FalconUA: You remember wrong. :) How do you think the smart pointers work? Heck, how do you think iterators work!?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Oh, yeah, iterators, forgot about them :D So we only cannot overload `.` :-?? Thanks xD

Answer (score 1):

An iterator is a "generalised pointer"—it's an object which behaves similarly to pointer pointing to an element in a container. This code:

```
itr = myList.begin();
itr->printData();
```

calls the `printData` function on the first object in the `myList` container. If `myList` was an array, it would mean the same as this:

```
ptr = &myList[0];
ptr->printData();
```

To answer your question about `abc`: if the object `abc` is the one to which the iterator `itr` refers ("points"), then indeed `itr->printData()` is equivalent to `(&abc)->printData()`.

---

It seems from your comments that you're asking how overloading `operator ->` actually works, which wasn't too clear from the question itself.

In general, operator overloading works such that when you use an operator in an expression and the operator is overloaded, the `operator` function is called and its return value is used as the value of the expression. For example:

```
struct MyClass {
  int x;
};

MyClass operator+ (const MyClass &lhs, const MyClass &rhs) {
  MyClass res;
  res.x = lhs.x + rhs.x;
  return res;
}

int main() {
  MyClass a{42}, b{21};
  MyClass c = a + b;
  //c.x is now 63
}
```

Some operators have slightly special treatment, and `->` is one of them. When used in an expression, it's always in the form `anObject -> someName`, where `anObject` is an ordinary object, but `someName` is the name of a member (variable or function). This is then resolved as follows: the return type of `operator ->` must be a pointer<sup>(1)</sup>, and the result of the expression will be the member `someName` of the object to which this returned pointer points.

In other words, when `p` is a pointer, the compiler transforms `p->someName` into `(*p).someName`. If `p` is an object with `operator ->` overloaded, it is instead transformed to `(*(p.operator->())).someName`.

---

<sup>(1)</sup> Not quite true: the return type must be a pointer, or something which has `operator->` overloaded. In the latter case, `operator->` will be called on the returned object, repeating the process until a pointer is eventually returned.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but as my understanding is "dataType* operator -> () const {}" is like a function, so I seperate itr->printData() to  itr-> and printData(),  "itr->" called the overloading operator function and would be returned a andress, so again its like &abcprintData()?

Comment: @whoisit OK, I hope I understand your question better now (the original is rather unclear). Can you confirm if the edited answer addresses your actual question?

Comment: sorry about the unclear original question, I have edit the question, so now it is my actual question, what I don't understand is obviously we can call a object's function by using its address added directly in front of the function like &abcprintData();

Comment: @whoisit Umm, no. That's not how C++ works at all. `&abcprintData()` is nonsense. What you can do is `abc.printData()` or `(&abc)->printData()`. The last one is similar to what happens when `->` is overloaded.